# IMacros If then else statement how to?

Tags: imacros

I am trying to make a script to automatically skip males and couples on a chat site, when i reach a couple the class is `gndr_couple` and the script returns an error and stops.

This is my current code:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR    
FRAME F=1    
WAIT SECONDS=0.5    
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:gndr_male    
WAIT SECONDS=0.2    
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:right_button
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: there are 3 classes the script have to stop when it reaches gndr_female but it stops when it reaches gndr_couple because there is no if else code in the script. i have no idea how to make it.

Comment: I have no idea where is that supposed to be in your code.